# Which layout should I use for HVGA screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Which layout should I use for HVGA screen? For a small screen, I put all my XML files in `layout-small` directory. Similarly for devices like Nexus S and Samsung Galaxy S which have a resolution of 480 x 800. I put all my XML files in the layout directory.

But for HVGA I didn't find any solution. Where to put the XML file for the HVGA device?

Is there any option like layout-small that I can do for HVGA devices?  When I run the for HGVA device it takes the layout from the layout directory but as the resolution for HVGA devices is smaller than Nexus S devices, the layout does not properly appear. So I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

> Normal: Screens that are of similar size to a medium-density HVGA
>   screen. The minimum layout size for a normal screen is approximately
>   320x470 dp units. Examples of such screens a WQVGA low density, HVGA
>   medium density, WVGA high density.
>
> MDPI: Medium-density (on traditional HVGA) screens; approximately
>   160dpi.

You should try: `drawable-normal-mdpi`

Comment: so i put my xml file in drawable-normal-mdpi directory

Comment: Yep, and if it s not working you could try drawable-normal or drawable-mdpi. Check the link everything is in it.

Comment: My answer is stupid, I give you info for drawable and you want layout. Have you create directories : layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge, and try in each of them ? Which API do you use ? Do you work in dpi ?

Answer (score 3):

To target HVGA 320*480 use:

```
layout-normal-mdpi
```

At the same time to support WVGA screens and i.e. Galaxy Tab you need:

```
layout-normal-hdpi
```

folders.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the layout of layout-large

you can refer following link ....

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: remove ur layouts from layout and place all ur layouts in layout-large, it will atomatically call its layout from layout-large and place ur drawables in drawablw-hdpi as i m also developiing layouts for samsung galaxy tab,same helped me